# Is there any Delegate method to enable Edit Button With Delete In TableView Cell Editing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm Working On a project in which i have to show Edit option like Delete in Table View Editing Style like in given picture.

[image]

**Is there any delegate method to Show Edit Option in TableView Cell Editing**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `editActionsForRowAt` delegate method. Check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614956-tableview)

> Asks the delegate for the actions to display in response to a swipe in
>   the specified row.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { (rowAction, indexPath) in
        //TODO: edit the row at indexPath here
    }
    editAction.backgroundColor = .gray

    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { (rowAction, indexPath) in
        //TODO: Delete the row at indexPath here
    }
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = .red

    return [deleteAction,editAction]
}
```